# Biometrics Appt for UK Visa help

Tags: visas, uk

I booked a biometrics appointment at a uscis La Brea-Los Angeles center, with a confirmed appointment stated on a document that I had to bring into the application center. This was issued to me via the UK Gov student Tier 4 Visa application website.

I was late to my appointment and called the Los Angeles location to re-book another day, only to be told I was not in the system for an appointment! Their advice was to call the UK Visa Gov website for further help, as they had no idea how to help me.

Upon calling the Uk Gov Visas and Immigration, I could get no help either. They referred me to someone in another department through e-mail and I have still not heard back.

This is so urgent as I was meant to leave in 2 weeks! I have no idea how to sign up for another appointment/don't even know WHERE to go as the only other options are premium services which are quite costly through a company called VFS.Global (recommended through the UK Visa website to buy a courier service.) I see that they have actual offices for the biometrics appointment but after reading reviews of this VFS.Global company online I would rather not use them. I can't have any delays in my visa arrival.

I've also read online that the Uscis has suspended their use for the UK Visa... I have NO clue why the actual UK gov would've allowed me to book an appointment through them leaving me with the only option to go premium? Is this true?

Does anyone know what I should do? Time is of the essence and I am literally so confused as to what to do next. This entire process has been very confusing. Thank you so much and sorry for the rambling in advance.

Comment: OP has now posted this question on Expats.